# Commutator space of regular nilpotent elements

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336245/lie-algebra-elements-commuting-with-a-principal-nilpotent-element).

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple complex Lie algebra, $A \in \mathfrak{g}$ a regular nilpotent element (i.e. its centralizer is of dimension equal to the rank of $\mathfrak{g}$). I wish to understand the set of elements which commute with A.

I would be happy if the answer is something like "the polynomials of $A$ which are still in $\mathfrak{g}$". So in order to make sens of polynomials, we need a representation of the Lie algebra.
So the precise question is:

*Is there a faithful irreducible representation $$ such that for all regular nilpotent elements $$ we have the following equality: $ \mathbb{C}[()]∩(\mathfrak{g})=(\mathfrak{z_g}())$ where $\mathfrak{z_g}()$ denotes the centralizer of $$?*

For example take $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. Then the standard representation fulfils the question since $$ is the matrix with 1 on the over-diagonal (up to conjugacy $A$ is unique here). And a matrix $$ commutes with $$ iff $=()$ with $$ a polynomial without constant term and of degree smaller than $$. This is due to the fact that $$ is cyclic here.

I also analyzed the question for $\mathfrak{so}_n$ where it works for
the standard representation. But I have no clue how to do it in general without a case by case treatment of the classical Lie algebras.

Comment: I added "faithful" because the 1-dimensional trivial representation satisfies the condition and is clearly not what you're interested in. Also maybe you know whether the question reduces to the case of $\mathfrak{g}$ simple. Namely, if $\rho_i$ works for $\mathfrak{g}_i$, $i=1,2$, does $\rho_1\otimes\rho_2$ work for $\mathfrak{g}_1\times\mathfrak{g}_2$?

Comment: I don't know the answer off-hand, but I'd like to point out that many properties of nilpotent elements and orbits *are* established on a case-by-case basis, with proofs in the exceptional cases also involving reduction to Levi components. The question itself appears close to Kostant's work on Toda lattices, which may be worth studying.

Comment: Does anything in the question https://mathoverflow.net/q/160891/27465 and/or its answers help here?